# Evaluating an integral

Tags: integral

Just want to make sure of something very simple. $X$ follows a distribution $F(\mu,\sigma^2)$. I want to calculate the integral of $XdF(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu=E(X)$ and $\sigma^2=Var(X)$.

Do I multiply and divide by $dx$ and then apply the chain rule to evaluate the integral?

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdF=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=E(X)=\mu$ (by definition of expectation)

Comment: But I want to calculate this integral between say 0 to t, where t is finite, how do i do that